# Routing a form/create object post request in rails--problems with the form and routing request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm pretty new to rails so sorry if this is poorly worded... for a course, I'm creating an app that lets you add (post) new instances of classes called Planets and Moons. Moon is supposed to be a child of Planet. Right now I can create both in separate database tables, using three route requests:

```
get "planets" => "planets#index"
get "planets/new" => "planets#new"
post "/planets" => "planets#create"
```

(This create a form page to register new planets. Substitute "moons" and the moon class works the same, including create, from it's own form page.)

I have a fourth route for a planets show-by-id page

```
get "planets/:id" => "planets#show"
```

On this planets id show page, I want to create an "Add a moon" form that takes the param ID for the planet, lets the user enter a moon name, and sends the post request to create the new instance.

I don't think I know enough about forms and routing.

My form for the new moons is

```
<%= form_for @moon, url: "/planets/:id" do |f| %>
  <p><strong>New Moon Name:</strong></p>
  <p>Name: <%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <% Planet.find(params[:id]: :planet_id %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Create!" %></p>
<% end %>
```

The three "moon" routes I have: 
     1) get "moons" => "moons#index"
     2) get "moons/new" => "moons#new" (goes to a form I was using to test, I don't know if I need this)
     3) post "/planets/:id" => "moons#create" (where I think the problem is)

I think I may need to use interpolation to get the planet ID from the params into the moon posting form so help there is great, but I'm more concerned with getting past the line:

```
 <%= form_for @moon, url: "/planets/:id" do |f| %>
```

I get error: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

This is what I have defined in the moons controller...

```
def new
  @moon = Moon.new
end

def create
  moon_attributes = params[:moon]

  Moon.create({
    name: moon_attributes[:name],
    planet_id: moon_attributes[:planet_id]
  })
end
```

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed by I can't answer my own question for 8 hours... It seems that replacing the url in the form markup with a direct call for a new instance will save a new instance to the database.. 

    <%= form_for Moon.new do |f| %>
    <p>Moon Name: <%= f.text_field :name %></p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :planet_id, :value => "#{planet.id}".to_i %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Add moon!" %></p>
    <% end %>

Routing is 

    get "moons" => "moons#index"
    get "moons/new" => "moons#new"
    post "/moons" => "moons#create"

Answer (score 0):

To give you some perspective, here's what you need to do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :planets, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show] do
   resources :moons, only: [:create] #-> planets/:id/moons
end
```

This uses the [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) structure in Rails, giving you the paths you have already anyway.

---

In terms of your form, you'd be best doing this:

```
#app/views/planets/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @moon do |f| #-> should route to  moons_controller#create %>
  <p><strong>New Moon Name:</strong></p>
  <p>Name: <%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Create!" %></p>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/moons_controller.rb
class MoonsController < ActiveRecord::Base
    def create
       moon = Moon.new(moon_params)
       moon.save
       redirect_to planets_show_path(planet)
    end

    private
    def moon_params
       params.require(:moon).permit(:name).merge(planet_id: params[:planet_id])
    end

end
```